# AttributeError: module 'cv2.aruco' has no attribute 'interpolateCornersCharuco'

Tags: python, opencv, aruco, pose-estimation

I'm working on a python script to do pose estimation using charuco board (https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/da9/tutorial_aruco_board_detection.html). I can already do it with single aruco marker, with some trouble with the documentation :/. Now I would like to a charuco board to do it and when I use interpolateCornersCharuco() I got this error. It seems the doc has change and I don't find what is the actual good signature for this function in python.
Does anyone know ?

ps : I'm using aruco library from opencv with python 3.10.11, opencv 4.7.0 and I'm on Windows.

```
board = aruco.CharucoBoard((row, col), squareLength, markerLenght, arUsedDictionnary)
charucoretval, charucoCorners, charucoIds = aruco.interpolateCornersCharuco(arMarkersCorners, arMarkersId, 
                                                                            grayImg, board)
computedImage = aruco.drawDetectedCornersCharuco(img, markerCorners, markersIds, (0,255,0))
retval, rvec, tvec = aruco.estimatePoseCharucoBoard(charucoCorners, charucoIds, board, cameraCalibrationMatrix, calibrationDistCoef)
```

Comment: what makes you think that function might exist? what if it no longer exists?

Comment: same issue after just switching to opencv-python==4.8.0.74  (note code worked with opencv-4.7)

Answer (score 1):

There Has been Significant Api Changes with the new releases of opencv

Updated Syntax

> charucodetector = cv2.aruco.CharucoDetector(board)

> charuco_corners, charuco_ids, marker_corners, marker_ids = charucodetector.detectBoard(image)

Earlier it was

> marker_corners, marker_ids, rejectedImgPoints =
> cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(
> image, dictionary)
>
> retval, charuco_corners, charuco_ids =
> cv2.aruco.interpolateCornersCharuco(
> marker_corners, marker_ids, image, board)

Answer (score 0):

It's been deprecated, use: [CharucoDetector::detectBoard](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d9/df5/classcv_1_1aruco_1_1CharucoDetector.html#aacbea601612a3a0feaa45ebb7fb255fd)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I already use this method, so I don't know what to do after call detectBoard() in order to do a pose estimation of the charuco board. I got charuco corners and ids from this method but after I want to get values like tvec and rvec from the board.

Answer (score 0):

try installing `opencv-contrib-python`, 
such as by running the following:

`pip uninstall opencv-python`
`pip install -U opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).